# Sets as opposed to arrays in Postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, set

I know you can insert an array into a Postgres DB using 'jsonb'. I'm wondering if the same can be done with a set. Can I insert a new Set into a 'jsonb' column and retain the 'uniqueness' properties that a set gives you over an array?

Comment: Isn't a JSONB object exactly that?  Just look at the keys and ignore the values. 
 `'{"a":1, "b":1, "c":1}'`

Comment: A JSONB column can also store arrays.

Comment: It can, but it doesn't have to. Are you looking for something that makes it impossible to store arrays?

Comment: I was just looking for something that will let me store an array. Whenever I want to push something onto that array, if that something already exists to not let me, which is what a set achieves.

Comment: That is an implementation detail.  Usually a set implementation will just not store the redundant added member, rather than throwing an error.  (Or it will replace the old member with the new one of the same name, but if there is no meaningful attached data then that is a distinction without a difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There are both the jsonb arrays and the regular array types (like int[]), but neither are sets that enforce uniqueness.